# What is the best way to display arithmetic operations in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-lmtx

[image]

I know the best way would be to use [xlop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHlA6.png) however, even if the result above was optained using it, there is some issues with ConTeXt.

Some examples:

- `\opadd[voperator=bottom]{123}{456.2}` returns

[image]

Yes... `123` is not displayed.

- `\opdiv[voperator=bottom]{12345.2}{6}` returns

[image]

Adding a decimal in the dividend seems to multiply everything by `10` here. And it will continue to multiply everything by `10` for each decimals. So `12345.23÷6` will be `1234523÷600`, etc.

We could continue for a long time enumerating [xlop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHlA6.png) issues when used with ConTeXt.

So, what is the best way to achieve all of that in ConTeXt since I do not have the level to fix those issues myself?

Comment: I don't know why xlop should work in ConTeXt? I do not know of any support for this kind of things in ConTeXt. If you want to suggest support for it, it is probably better to write to the mailing list.

Comment: I did not said that xlop should work in ConTeXt. I can see, according to all the issues there is with that combination, that it does not. This is why I was asking if there is any better way to do the same things.

Comment: You can consider either email the author, or typeset the result yourself manually, or reimplement the feature in ConTeXt. If you don't know how to program the feature (side note, in ConTeXt you can freely use Lua so it's easier to program in), you'll have to typeset them manually then.